# VB Script split issue

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I use the split function of in VBScript to split the string. Below is the code am using.

```
Dim inputText
DIM resultArray 

inputText = "abc; def; ""xyz;123"""
resultArray = Split(inputText, "; ")

For i = 0 To UBound(resultArray)
    resultArray(i) = Replace(resultArray(i), """", "")          
    resultArray(i) = Replace(resultArray(i), ";", "")
    IF i = UBound(resultArray) THEN
        Response.Write resultArray(i)
    ELSE
        Response.Write resultArray(i) & ";&nbsp;"
    END IF
Next
```

If i remove the space after ; in split function it will also split "xyz:123" which i don't want to be.

Either i gave space after ; in split function (Line # 4) or not it shouldn't split the "xyz:123" which comes in double quotes.

Any suggestion how i can achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think first i need to replace the ; in xyz:123 with nothing as i also don't need this in final outcome of script. Am i right here ?

Comment: @Umar Siddique: I wouldn't go down that path. Who knows what other similar problems you run into. It's almost like parsing XHTML with a regex (okay who's alarm just went off? ;)). Not the right tool for the job, but there's an alternative.

Comment: @Rob thanks for helping. Yes you are right, but this input string format is final and it couldn't be anything else. So am looking for a short solution.

Comment: @Umar the solution I posted might look longer than it is. :) If you copy the sample code, you can adjust it fairly simply I think, and you'll have a rather solid solution. Otherwise you'll have to come up with some pretty nasty string operations that will be more error-prone. Writing and testing that will likely cost more time than using objects that are already capable of handling these situations well.

Comment: @Robe. Ok fine, you are right. But am bit confused with csv file as i think in my case its just a simple string which may b in a text file etc.

Comment: @Umar I admit I was guessing about it being csv, but the string you provided as an example, coupled with the description of what you want (ie: any delimiter between double quotes ignored) and the problem you're trying to solve, tell me you want to parse a csv string or file. I'd be surprised if that was a coincidence. If you exported the text file from an application, I have pretty much no doubt that you're dealing with csv. I hope you'll get it to work the way you were aiming for.

Comment: Yes i want to parse a csv string which i provided above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That suspiciously looks like a csv-file. You could try using ADO for this. Microsoft has a fairly extensive (and very useful) article on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx

Since they describe exactly your problem, I think that just might be your solution. :)

Comment: I think this sounds like a perfect answer to the question at hand. Great eye in seeing the similarities of CSV as I was looking in a direction 180 degrees opposite.